# Организация общения десктопного приложения с сервером SQL

Tags: sql, права

У меня пока есть три варианта организации доступа:

1. Создание сервиса-посредника. Все
   запросы отправляются на специальный
   сервис, а он уже возвращает данные.
   Авторизация так же проходит через
   него - существуют одно имя входа на
   SQL-сервер, через которое
   подулючается сервис, у сервиса есть
   таблица пользователей и он уже рулит
   доступом.
2. Опять же одно имя входа - вводится единожды или же поставляется с приложением и хранится в шифрованном виде, а управление доступом производит само приложение.
3. Использование системы безопасности самого sql-сервера.

Третий вариант мне совсем не нравится. Разводится помойка имен входа. Это я конкретно про MS SQL, т.к. работа ведется сейчас с ним. Но планируется так же и проэкты основанные на MySQL.

Собственно хочу услышать Ваши мнения и предложения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Видел все три этих решения в действии... Давайте по пунктам

3) Имеет ряд плюсов (в частности прозрачность и достаточно надежная защита данных), но при этом создает помойку из аккаунтов и местами избыточный код и настройки прав на хранимой логике.

2) Хранить пароль на вход в шифрованном виде в приложении = хранить его в открытом виде. Потому, что если ваше приложение может расшифровать пароль, то и злобные хакеры могут расшифровать пароль. Единственное приемлимое исключение - удаленные приложения. Тогда враги не могут поковырять кишки приложения. Ну и в таких случаях, часто вопросы безопасности оставляют на совести приложение - а это плохо.

1) Архитектура - Клиент-Сервер-Сервер. На мой взгляд - самая лучшая архитектура. Плюсы: гибкий контроль прав доступа пользователей. Высокое быстродействие, за счет кеширования на сервер приложений и возможности передавать только те данные, которые реально нужны, а не те, которые нравятся серверу БД. Минусы: объективно больший объем программирования; нужно больше серверов (хотя можно пробовать экономить на клиентах).

Переходите на веб-ориентированную разработку... за ней будущее)

Answer (score 1):

Я только про 3-й вариант. Раз у вас MS SQL, то, я полагаю, пользователи на Винде -> есть домен. В MS SQL можно выдать права группе пользователей и рулить правами через наполнение групп AD -> никакой помойки и прозрачное управление доступом на уровне данных.

Comment: Согласен, но как я написал планируется так же разработка на базе MySQL